# issue with python chloropleth maps - if you zoom in, there are very faint blue lines

Tags: python, maps

I am creating these COVID19 maps using python's chloropleth map features that are described here: https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/

So , with this, I am having to use import libraries, such as: json', pandas, plotly.express.

I created this map (where I pulled data from NYTimes github - these are daily incremental cases by the way, for 1 date in this case):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSQiS.png)

Now, if you zoom in close to the map, you see very blue faint lines. Does anyone know why it's there and how to remove that? See attached image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0SUe.png)

So, the reason that this is a problem, is that later when I am doing 'iid random sampling' on just the places where there are 'incremental COVID19 cases', it thinks those 'faint blue lines' has "COVID19 cases" so it does 'iid random sampling' there when it should not. Also, fyi - I do this 'iid random sampling' in MATLAB. See what I'm talking about here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im7Yw.png)
So, on the right side of map, it puts little black dots (where it is the 'iid random sampling' in the places where the faint blue lines were, when it should only put it where there are actualy real incremental cases, like the two spots on the left side of map)

I'm not sure if there is an issue with the library or packing that creates these chloropleth maps in python, which is what creates these faint blue lines? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok sure, can i Just upload my python code here?

Comment: How do I attach a python code file?

Comment: When I try to copy and paste, the indentation gets all messed up :(